# Wordpress shortcode not generating markup properly

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

I'm trying to use a shortcode to create some dropdown 'tabs' for my content, but I can't get the markup to render properly. I'm trying to get this:

```
<div class="tab">
  <h2 class="reytab">Title</h2>
  <div class="tab-content">...content appears here...</div>
</div>
```

But using the shortcode below, the content is being returned after everything else in the shortcode has been parsed instead of in-between the `<div class="tab-content"></div>`:

**Shortcode**

```
function reytab($atts, $content = null) {
       extract(shortcode_atts(array('title' => '#'), $atts));
       return '<div class="tab"><h2 class="reytab">' . $title . '</h2><div class="tab-content">' . do_shortcode($content) . '</div></div><!-- End div.tab -->';

}
add_shortcode('reytab', 'reytab');
```

**Markup generated from shortcode**

```
<div class="tab">
  <h2 class="reytab">Title</h2>
  <div class="tab-content"></div>
</div>
...content appears here...[\reytab]
```

The fact that `[\reytab]` is appearing at the end suggests to me that something is preventing the shortcode executing fully when it reaches `$content`.

Can anyone see the problem?

Thanks,

Osu

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing what your passing to your shortcode its hard to say..
have you looked through the Nested Shortcodes & Limitations? [DOCS](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API)

are you using shortcodes nested within each other?
ie:

```
[reytab title='Tabs Title']this is my gallery [gallery id=3][/reytab]
```

looks fine to me. just tested on my blog and it works, using both inline text & a short code for the gallery

```
function reytab_shortcode($atts, $content = null) {
       extract(shortcode_atts(array('title' => '#'), $atts));
       $myShotcode = '<div class="tab">';
       $myShotcode.= '<h2 class="reytab">'.$title.'</h2>';
       $myShotcode.= '<div class="tab-content">'.do_shortcode($content).'</div>';
       $myShotcode.= '</div>';
       return $myShotcode;
}
add_shortcode('reytab', 'reytab_shortcode');
```

then in your post and pages you could write somthing like.

```
[reytab title='Tabs Title']
this is my gallery [whichevershortcodeyouwant]
[/reytab]
```

hopefully this should be ok.

Marty

**RE-EDIT**

```
function reytab_shortcode($atts, $content=null) {
    extract(shortcode_atts(array('title' => '#'), $atts));
    $myShotcode = '<div class="tab">';
    $myShotcode.= '<h2 class="reytab">'.$title.'</h2>';
    $myShotcode.= '<div class="tab-content">'.do_shortcode($content).'</div>';
    $myShotcode.= '</div>';
    return $myShotcode;
}
```

Comment: thanks for getting back to me. I'm confused as well as it should be working from what I can see. What I'm passing my shortcode in the WP editor is this: `[reytab title="Title"]...wysiwyg content...[/reytab]`, so it should be working right? Is it possible another shortcode is messing up how this one is parsed?

Comment: Oh, and I'm not nesting shortcodes by the way, but I've tried with and without do_shortcode() and it gives the same result

Comment: so are you trying to encapsulate the entire content of the post or page within your shortcode tags? if im thinking straight im sure you can just remove the content from the function all together? see re-edit above, infact no dont bother... just checked it leaves it out.

Comment: this is driving me crazy. I've tried it in the Twentyten theme to see if it was a theme-specific issue, but no difference. For all I can see, this really should be working. Have you any other ideas what I could check? My theme is a child theme i.e. I'm using TwentyEleven as the parent theme, so it could be that TwentyEleven is the issue? Really confused! If it helps, here's my entire functions.php file: http://pastie.org/3490450

Comment: Stupidly, I overlooked the shortcode tag and realised I was using `[\reytab]` instead of `[/reytab]`....[walks away head down]...

Thanks for your help @Marty

Comment: oh m8, gutter :) h8 those little picky things they eat away at your brain :| glad to help